# Fade jQuery Logo Based on Scroll Position

Tags: jquery, scroll-position

I'm trying to accomplish a task with jQuery (newbie) and I've nearly figured everything out except for one step. I have a logo that fades out after scrolling 250px down the page. I also have a top nav that slides down and pushes the logo down with it. If it's past 250px down the page, the logo's opacity reappears and then disappears when closing the nav. This is all working properly.

My issue is when I'm within the first 250px of the page. When I open and close the nav, the logo completely fades out upon closing the nav. I would like for it to return to the opacity that it would have been at based on the scroll position with the first 250px of the page.

Example (must be viewed in a browser wider than 768px): http://staging.michalekbrothersracing.com/

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<!--LOGO FADE-->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var top=$(this).scrollTop();
        if(top<250){
            var dif=1-top/250;
            $(".logo").css({opacity:dif});
        }
    })
});

function toggle(id) {
      var el = document.getElementById(id);
      var box = el.getAttribute("class");
      if(box == "hide"){
          el.setAttribute("class", "show");
          $('.logo').fadeTo(250, '1');
      }
      else{
          el.setAttribute("class", "hide");
          $('.logo').fadeTo(250, '0');
      }
  }
```

I believe my "else" statement is what's screwing this up. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to begin adding in rules based on where the scroll position is when toggling the nav.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Just a comment.. dont use html comments in scripts.

Comment: Doesn't look like it pushes the logo down now, did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
//logo fade
//store the top
var _top=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        //store into the var
        _top=$(this).scrollTop();
        if(_top<250){
            _dif=1-_top/250;
            $(".logo").css({opacity:dif});
        }
    })
});

//this is when you click the menu
function toggle(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var box = el.getAttribute("class");
    if(box == "hide"){
        el.setAttribute("class", "show");
        //menu is on - no need to fade in
        //$('.logo').fadeTo(250, '1');
    }
    else{
        el.setAttribute("class", "hide");
        //fade the logo back in
        if(_top<250){
            var dif=1-_top/250;
            $(".logo").css({opacity:dif});
        }
        else
        {
            $('.logo').fadeTo(250, '0');
        }
    }
}
```